# Chrome doesn't request for swf files

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I have problem with flash files in Chrome. These files can appear on the page, but if you make a refresh they can (and often do) disappear. When I watch "network" tab I see that Chrome doesn't even request swf's. When they are shown in "network" tab they have status 304.

Comment: Can you show your HTML code, or a link?

Comment: http://bulgaria-home.su/

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations of the object-embed code. All this doesn't work/

Comment: Could be something relaed to the server. It seems to drop connection randomly. Displays different errormessages on every other pageload as well.

Comment: But why it works in other browsers?